# controlling the size of textarea with jeditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, textarea

**My objective:** Allowing inline-edition of a description with the jquery plugin jeditable.

**My problem:** The textarea input is bigger than the original div, leading to the apparition of scroll-bars.

**Attempted solution:**

```
$('.editableDescription').editable('http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/', {

id: 'data[Chantier][id]',
name: 'data[Chantier][Description]',
type: 'textarea',
height: $(".editableDescription").height() + "px",
width:  $(".editableDescription").width()+ "px",
onblur: 'submit',
tooltip: ''

});​
```

I tried to take the size of the wrapper div with jquery, but it still fails!

**jsFiddle:**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FShmW/7/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to remove `height:250px;` from `.longtext`, or else Jeditable will take it as the default height for the `<textarea>`.

Then I made sure that `.longtext` had the same styles as the `<textarea>` that will be nested inside it, such as `line-height, font-size, font-family`.

And I assumed that you'll probably have more than one `.longtext` in your document, so you will need to apply different `heights` to different `<textarea>s`. So I changed this:

```
$('.editableDescription').editable('http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
{
        id        : 'data[Chantier][id]',
        name      : 'data[Chantier][Description]',
        type      : 'textarea',
        height:($(".editableDescription").height()) + "px",
        width: ($(".editableDescription").width()) + "px",
        onblur: 'submit',
        tooltip   : ''
});
```

​
to this:

```
$('.editableDescription').each(function()
{
    $(this).editable('http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
    {
        id:'data[Chantier][id]',
        name:'data[Chantier][Description]',
        type:'textarea',

        height:$(this).height()+'px',
        /* here it will take the height of the currently active .longtext */

        width:$(this).width()+'px',
        onblur:'submit',
        tooltip: ''
   });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FShmW/8/)**

And that's basically it.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: @snuffn thanks for this one!! I was so glad when your trick solved my problem in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gberginc/G38dv/31/ (H, Q and Tv columns are editable).

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set the CSS overflow property to hidden

Comment: It does suppress the scroll-bars of course. But it doesn't solve the size problem.